# php header issue wont redirrect on duplicate function

Tags: header

I have two nearly identical php functions both are functioning but for some reason the header will only run on the first one. I have no idea why this could be happening. I've seen some similarly titled post but none have solved or are the same as the problem I have so please don't remove this question. I've tried removing the closing php tag no help I've tried just about everything you could imagine but no cigar. the code is definitely running as echo's work at the end of the code so does exit(); but for some reason header just doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated I will try anything. Also the reason I need this to work is so that when the page is refreshed it doesn't resubmit the form. I know this isn't much to go on so feel free to ask me questions.

```
function setComments($conn){
if (isset($_POST['commentsubmit'])) {

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) values('$uid','$date', '$message')";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    header("Location: videos.php");

}
```

}

duplicate code with alterations.

```
function setComments2($conn){

if (isset($_POST['commentsubmit2'])) {

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments2 (uid, date, message) values('$uid','$date','$message')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    header("Location: home.html");

}
```

}

Comment: Relative to the script with these functions, is the videos.php and home.html at the same path level? (meaning that one is NOT in a different directory than the other?)

Comment: Yeah they're both in the same directory I was just using home so that I could visually see if the header was working without having to refresh the page. I tried it with videos.php and it still didn't work.

Comment: Are these functions (the header() calls) located AFTER other code?  PHP.net says this: "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file."

Comment: That's so weird I actually tried that previously and had no luck but I just re tried it and it worked. I'm thinking now it was because I forgot to add location before the address a while ago and fixed it and must not have re tried with the fixed snippet. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it this has been bugging me for a couple of days now. You should post that as an answer so that I can say you answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header function calls were located AFTER other code.

PHP.net says this:

> "Remember that header() must be called **BEFORE** any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file."